# git finding the file name of the file being filtered by a smudge/clean filter

Tags: git, filter

I am creating a smudge/clean git filter.  The filter will need to know the name
of the file being filtered so that it can perform some external operations that
the result of which will be output by the filter.

Since the filters are read from stdin and write to stdout, **is there any way to
get the file name being filtered?**

for example I want to:

```
git blame $0  | cut -d " " -f 4-6 | sort | uniq | sort | tail -1
```

to find out the date of the last change in this file or:

```
git grep -I --name-only -e "" -- $0
```

to test if the file is binary.

However, I need to know what should I use as "`$0`" to make this work from inside the filter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `gitattributes` [manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html)

> Sequence "%f" on the filter command line is replaced with the name of the file the filter is working on. A filter might use this in keyword substitution. For example:
>
> > [filter "p4"]
> >
> > ```
> >    clean = git-p4-filter --clean %f
> >    smudge = git-p4-filter --smudge %f
> > ```

Maybe `%f` is what you want.

Comment: That looks like what I was looking for.  I'll test and let you know.