# Git clean filter - retrieve original line, git smudge but not original line

Tags: git

I have lines I want to completely ignore for the purpose checkout/diff/stage etc:

```
set(ROOT /path/to/something/name_suffix)
set(ROOT /path/to/something/othername_suffix)
```

and occasionally (but not always) I will have it as

```
set(ROOT /some/other/private/path/name)
set(ROOT /some/other/private/path/othername)
```

Ignoring means:

1. **~smudge:** If I checkout it out, nothing is done. If it matches the index, it will stay the same. If it was changed, it will stay the same.
2. **clean**: It won't be considered for the purpose of diff or git add.

What I have:

1. Git filter that smudges to my private path - problem with this is if I have the original line, upon checkout it will be reverted to my changed line (with the personal path):

   ```
   smudge = "sed 's#set\\(ROOT\\) .*/\\([a-z]*\\).*)#\\1 /some/other/private/path/\\2)#'"
   ```

I did not implement a git clean yet because the only way I currently see to do this is either a script that hard-codes the original suffix or something that analyzes `git diff` to see what was originally committed (the problem is the `_suffix`, I can't tell what it is from the working tree. The original path can be hard-coded, it will not change), and replace it with what was indexed. I do not want my private path to contain `_suffix` directories.

There are two things here:

1. Is this possible for git smudge - not changing the original line to the personal line if it is indeed exactly the same as it originally was?
2. Is there another solution for the clean filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your smudge script should save the captured group in a file of the same name, with a `.smudge` extension (for instance), and a `.gitignore` including `*.smudge`.

That way, your clean filter script can read the original value from the xxx.smudge, and restore the file to its original content through a reverse `sed`.

You can [pass the file name to your scripts using `%f`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005887/6309). (see [`.gitattributes#filters`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_filter))

Comment: Thanks, that's half the answer. I'll wait to see if someone catches the "smudge" part.

Comment: Undeleted - I want smudge to do nothing on checkout if the original line was unchanged (rather then smudging it).

Comment: BTW, I like this solution, especially since we can use a `.<name>.smudge` filename so it does not appear in ls at all.

Comment: @kabanus " if the original line was unchanged"? But when you checkout that file, the original line is by definition unchanged... I don't exactly get your use case.

Comment: If I have a smudge filter, even if the original line was unchanged, it will be changed after checkout. If I smudge "aaa" to "bbb", and my index and workarea both contain "aaa", after `git checkout <file>` it will change the "aaa" to "bbb". The use case is that often I will use the global paths,  and often my private paths, and I don't want to worry about it unless I change it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

As VonC suggested : you can actually pass the name of the file that is being worked on to your clean/smudge scripts [using `%f`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004887/git-finding-the-file-name-of-the-file-being-filtered-by-a-smudge-clean-filter/17005887#17005887).

One way to have your smudge filter "preserve" the current state of the target lines is :

- read the current content of `%f` from disk, and identify the lines you want to keep,
- replace in STDIN the lines you want to preserve.

You may use `sed`, or any scriptable way to replace text.

---

Note that, in general, if you swiitch from one branch to another, the target file may not be as you expect -- does it exist at all in your current worktree ? did its format change between two branches ?.

That being said, the above should still cover most of your use cases.

Comment: This gave me an idea to just tell sed to skip lines that contain the original root path on the smudge, thanks.